# Detect compiler used for EXE file

Tags: compile

Is there any way to detect (or to hide) the compiler that was used to build an executable file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[PEiD](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/PEiD) is pretty good

> PEiD detects most common packers,
> cryptors and compilers for PE files.
> It can currently detect more than 600
> different signatures in PE files.
>
> PEiD is special in some aspects when
> compared to other identifiers already
> out there!
>
> 1. It has a superb GUI and the interface is really intuitive and
>    simple.
> 2. Detection rates are amongst the best given by any other identifier.
> 3. Special scanning modes for *advanced* detections of modified and unknown files.
> 4. Shell integration, Command line support, Always on top and Drag'n'Drop
>    capabilities.
> 5. Multiple file and directory scanning with recursion.
> 6. Task viewer and controller.
> 7. Plugin Interface with plugins like Generic OEP Finder and Krypto
>    ANALyzer.
> 8. Extra scanning techniques used for even better detections.
> 9. Heuristic Scanning options.
> 10. New PE details, Imports, Exports and TLS viewers
> 11. New built in quick disassembler.
> 12. New built in hex viewer.
> 13. External signature interface which can be updated by the user.

Comment: "PEiD detects most common [...] compilers for PE files." that's what the readme says - actually it does not tell how to achive that

Comment: @Sathya Note, the included link is now dead.

Comment: @DuckMaestro updated witi an alternative link

Comment: If it cannot detect the compiler something like _Nothing found [Overlay] *_ will be shown - which is confusing if you use that tool for the first time.

Comment: "The site ahead contains harmful programs" - Google Chrome. [Here's a better link.](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Packers-Crypters-Protectors/PEiD-updated.shtml)

Answer (score 13):

Try the *nix utility [strings](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?strings).  Using `strings -a foo.exe`  should produce a pile of results.  Redirect to a file and examine in your favorite editor.  You may see either a line that directly implicates a specific compiler, such as **Borland C++ - Copyright 2002 Borland Corporation**.  You might only be able to find lines that imply a specific compiler was used, such as in an include path or whatever.

Strings is also available for windows as part of [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), or as part of the [microsoft sysinternals package](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx).

Comment: It doesn't show me the compiler name only some dll names project

Answer (score 7):

When this question was asked, PEiD was only a couple of years out of date.

These days, you're probably better off using Detect It Easy: https://github.com/horsicq/DIE-engine/releases or https://horsicq.github.io/#detect-it-easydie

[image: Detect It Easy showing detection of curl.exe compiled with MSVC]

[image: Detect It Easy showing detection of ffmpeg.exe compiled with MinGW GCC]

Answer (score 4):

(Old but okay..)

**Language 2000** : http://farrokhi.net/language

Answer (score 2):

Not free, but IDA Pro has a very nice compiler detection. Not it's main function of course, but a nice extra.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a way to examine the first dozen or so bytes of the EXE file, in a hex dump with corresponding ASCII characters displayed, they will usually indicate the compiler used.

Comment: i was wondering if someone or some software can find if the exe was build with a specific compiler edition (Visual Studio 2010  Professional or Enterprise or Express)

Comment: This usually isn't true. The first part of a PE file is the DOS stub which is usually a program that prints something like "This program cannot be run in DOS mode."

Answer (score 1):

You can use "dependency walker" to check what runtime library it links to. MSVCP100 is Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86

Comment: linking to MSVC runtime doesn't mean that it's been compiled by MSVC